# Typedef With A Class In Another Class

Tags: c++, class, oop, typedef

```
class A{

  public:
    A(){ letter = 66; }
    void display(void){ cout << "A = " << letter; }

  private:
    int letter;

};


class B{

  public:
    typedef A classA;
};

int main(void){

   B::classA objA;

   objA.display();

   return 0;

}
```

This code runs properly ;however, I cannot understand what we do in this code.
I have never seen something like this before. It seems like class A is a member of class B. If it is so, why do not we use classA through object of class B ?

Comment: `class A` is not a member of `B`, `classA` is... and `classA` is just another name for `class A`. So in this case `B::classA a;` and `A a;` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like class A is a member of class B. If it is so, why do not we use classA through object of class B ?

No. What you have there is a *name* (a type in this case) declared in `class B` as `classA` which stands as a typedef to a class, `A`. In C++, the name of a class is also a namespace. so the typedef, lets you access a name `classA` within `class B`.

> I have never seen something like this before.

For your specific example, it may be an overkill. But having type aliases is very useful and you will find it a lot in many *class templates* codes.

Consider:

```
template<typename T>
class B{
  public:
    typedef T classA;
};
```

Without the `typedef` above, it would be very difficult to tell what type the above class was instantiated with.

A typical example is how STL algorithms can tell the category of a given iterator by accessing the name [`iterator_category`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) from the iterator's type via `std::iterator_traits`

Answer (score 1):

The class definition `class B { typedef A classA; }` does not define any data member in class `B`; with `typedef`, it introduces a new name `classA` as a synonym for type `class A`). Because this typedef-name is defined within `class B`, it is in the namespace of class `B`, such that you need to refer to this new type as `B::classA`, which is then equivalent to `A`.  Confer, for example, the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf):

> 7.1.3 The typedef specifier
>
> (1) Declarations containing the decl-specifier typedef declare identifiers that can be used later for naming. ... 
>   A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type.
>   ...

BTW: A common way for introducing aliases is also the `using`-statement:

```
using classA = A;
```

> (2) A typedef-name can also be introduced by an alias-declaration. The
>   identifier following the using keyword becomes a typedef-name and the
>   optional attribute-specifier-seq following the identifier appertains
>   to that typedef-name. It has the same semantics as if it were
>   introduced by the typedef specifier. In particular, it does not define
>   a new type and it shall not appear in the type-id.

Comment: afaik strictly speaking a `typedef` does not introduce a new type, but just an alias, just as in `int & a = x;` there isnt a new variable, but `a` is just an alias for `x`

Comment: @tobi303: right - `typedef` does not introduce a new type, but a new typedef-name; adapted the answer.